# Remotely accessing a LAN device

Tags: networking, remote-desktop, lan, putty, remote-access

I have Local Area Network where different devices are assigned IP between 192.168.7.2 to 192.168.7.172. External gateway is 192.168.7.11, which is a Mikrotik router.

I need to remotely access one of my device i.e 192.168.7.114 using putty. Only the main router has a static IP provided by ISP.

What IP should I enter in 'putty' or 'Remote-Desktop' to access 192.168.7.114?

Answer (score 2):

1. Set up port forwarding on your router so that incoming putty connections (default port 513) are routed to 192.168.7.114
2. find out your router static IP
3. from outside your network, type: `<router IP>:513` and the request should first go to your router, then be directed to 192.168.7.114